# Horizontal scroll work incorrectly in devexpress gridcontrol tableview

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I'm using devexpress gridcontrol tableview in my MVVM project. When I open app in small screen horizontal scroll work incorrectly. Data stay in place but column headers scrolls. I tried to use tips in DevExpress support center and them manuals, but it is not working.  Here is my XAML code:

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="GridControl"
                 dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="LightGray"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
                 SelectionMode="Row"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

            <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="" 
                                FieldName="Left" 
                                HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" 
                                Width="1" FixedWidth="True" AllowResizing="False" Fixed="Left"
                                AllowSorting="True" AllowGrouping="False" AllowAutoFilter="False"
                                Visible="False" 
                                AllowBestFit="True" BestFitArea="Rows"/>
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="" 
                                FieldName="Right" 
                                HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" 
                                Width="1" FixedWidth="True" AllowResizing="False" Fixed="Right"
                                AllowSorting="True" AllowGrouping="False" AllowAutoFilter="False"
                                Visible="False" 
                                AllowBestFit="True" BestFitArea="Rows"/>
                <!-- Column example -->                
                <dxg:GridColumn Header="Head" 
                                FieldName="Name" 
                                HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" 
                                Width="1" FixedWidth="True" AllowResizing="False" Fixed="Left"
                                AllowSorting="True" AllowGrouping="False" AllowAutoFilter="False"
                                Visible="False" 
                                AllowBestFit="True" BestFitArea="Rows"/>
                ...
            </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

            <dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
                <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TechnologyName" SummaryType="Count"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>

            <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
                <dxg:GridSummaryItem SummaryType="Count" Alignment="Right"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>

            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView x:Name="gridView"
                               dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="MetropolisLight"
                               ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" 
                               WaitIndicatorType="Panel" 
                               ShowFilterPanelMode="Never" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" AllowFilterEditor="False" 
                               AutoWidth="False" AllowFixedColumnMenu="True" AllowPerPixelScrolling="True"
                               HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Visible" AllowScrollHeaders="False" 
                               NavigationStyle="Row"
                               AllowEditing="False" 
                               ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowGrouping="False"
                               ShowSearchPanelMode="Never"
                               AllowBestFit="True" BestFitArea="Header"> 
                    <dxg:TableView.DataRowTemplate>
                    <!-- Row template -->
                        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dxg:TableView.AutoWidth = false` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Max. I have the same problem and have no idea how to solve it by GridControl settings. I use this workaround:  try to wrap your gridControl by the ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      Grid.Row="0">
            <dxg:GridControl x:Name="realPipeLineWorkGridControl"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             MaxHeight="8000"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"...
```